# Not able to execute test cases via programatically suite generation

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have a Maven project for my Selenium Automation. I am programatically executing the test cases. I have built the class `DynamicSuiteHelper.java` for creating my suite dynamically. When I run this from my Eclipse IDE it executes as expected. Now, I want to execute this code using Maven.

So first I did `mvn clean install`. And then when I ran the automation.jar file it started execution, but the results show that 0 tests were ran. So I checked back in the output folder, which showed the suite file was created and it was created as I intended.

I am using three plugins:

1) maven-surefire:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</plugin>
```

2) maven-compiler:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

3) maven-shade: (for generating executable jars)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>com.project.automation.tests.DynamicSuiteHelper</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also the test classes are in the same package as the DynamicSuiteHelper.java class.

Code snippet for DynamicSuiteHelper class:

```
    TestNG dynamicTestNG = new TestNG();
    XmlSuite dynamicSuite = new XmlSuite();
    List<XmlTest> listOfTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
    XmlTest dynamicTest = new XmlTest(dynamicSuite);
    List<XmlClass> listOfClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    listOfClasses.add(new XmlClass("com.project.automation.tests.test1.Test1Class1"));
    listOfClasses.add(new XmlClass("com.project.automation.tests.test1.Test1Class2"));
    listOfClasses.add(new XmlClass("com.project.automation.tests.test2.Test2Class1"));
    listOfClasses.add(new XmlClass("com.project.automation.tests.test2.Test2Class1"));
    dynamicTest.setClasses(listOfClasses );
    listOfTests.add(dynamicTest);
    dynamicSuite.setTests(listOfTests);
    List<XmlSuite> listOfSuites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    listOfSuites.add(dynamicSuite);
    dynamicTestNG.setXmlSuites(listOfSuites);
    dynamicTestNG.run();
```

Also the project structure looks like:

```
project
 |--automation
      |--tests
           |--test1
                |--Test1Class1.java
                |--Test1Class2.java
           |--test2
                |--Test2Class1.java
                |--Test2Class2.java
           |--BaseTest.java
           |--DynamicSuiteHelper.java
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define the classes for your tests in your dynamic suite helper?

Comment: Forgot to added that POC. Added the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and got the test cases up and running.

Instead of `maven-shade-plugin` I used the `maven-assembly-plugin`. I added the test classes externally from plugin, and also some resources.

What I observed was, `maven-shade-plugin` was not compiling my test-classes. So I tried out with `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Thanks again everyone for giving your time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in your main class. You are referring to the class as `com.automation.tests.test1.Test1Class1` but the folder structure you shared doesn't match with the package name (shouldn't it be `com.project.automation.tests.test1.Test1Class1` and so on for the other classes ? ) .

So TestNG is basically throwing an exception and aborting execution, but since your verbosity is set to `1` you perhaps aren't even seeing those exceptions.

The `XmlClass` has another constructor variant wherein you can refer to the class name directly (see [javadocs here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/7.0.0-beta1/org/testng/xml/XmlClass.html#XmlClass-java.lang.Class-))  instead of resorting to a fully qualified class name as a string (this can be highly error prone and I personally stay away from using this).

Also adding the line `dynamicTestNG.setVerbose(2);` to your code would ensure that you start seeing these errors as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input Krishnan. But what I observed was, even though I removed the surefire plugin from my pom file, and did a mvn clean install, the console showed surefire plugin is running tests, but the suite is not the one which the DynamicSuiteHelper is creating. But when I manually add the same suite to surefire plugin it will work fine as its supposed to. Also, earlier when I ran the mvn clean install, in the target folder, the test-classes showed there were no tests. Could it be related to maven convention? And if yes can you share a url?  Thanks, Sagar.

Comment: I tried with verbose=2. I was getting the following message: `[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run`. I suspected that the test classes were not being added, and unfortunately it turned out to be true. Let me look into this and get back.